# бот телеграм на PHP

Tags: php, telegram-bot

возможно ли сделать так что-бы
на сообщения отвечали по колонам, так сказать
запретить отвечать на другие сообщения
например

```
===========Первая колона============
if ($text == 'order') {
   $method = 'sendMessage';
   $data = [
   'text' = 'no orders'
   ];
   //и здесь еще доступную команду
}
===================================

==========Вторая колона============
if ($text == 'order 2') {
   $method = 'sendMessage';
   $data = [
   'text' = 'no orders'
   ];
   //и здесь еще доступную команду
}
===================================
```

Comment: Что есть колонна? и что значит запретить отвечать? удалять такие сообщения?

Comment: Я просто сказал примерно, ты не понял о чем я?

Comment: [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2601/%d0%92%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80-%d0%9a%d0%bb%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2)